# How to generalize balanced and absorbing sets to R-modules?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, modules

I'm looking for generalizing the notions of balanced set and absorbing set. The goal is using them for analyzing topological R-modules with R being a unit ring.

It's easy to generalize balanced and absorbing sets to a metrizable division ring, since we only need a unit ball and invertible elements. Seth Warner does so for absolute valued division rings in his *Topological Fields* (1989). In fact, I think that it can also work on uniform spaces and that the division property may be not necessary. But if R is not uniformizable, I don't have any idea about how to "generalize the unit ball", which is the key concept to generalize balanced and absorbing sets.

So, I ask you for references or any kind of help you can offer to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One can generalize "balanced" and "absorbing" to [bornological](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornological_space) rings. $\;$

Comment: Don't you want $R$ to be a topological ring? Then it is canonically a uniform space.